# OpenGL mipmap issue when scaling uv

Tags: opengl, mipmaps

I've just added an uv-scaling feature and I've discovered that the mipmapping is not working as I expected. I pass this scale to the shader which simply multiplies the input texcoord with this value.

However the result is "ziggy" like when I don't have any mipmap. This is because I modified the texture coordinates and the driver don't know which mip level it should choose.

How should I handle this kind of situation?

Comment: So you are scaling by large factors, effectively magnifying the texture/image?

Comment: @ltjax
I'm using (5.0, 5.0) scale right know which means the texture on the model (it's a plane) is repeated 5 times for each direction because I'm using GL_REPEAT. If you're familiar with Unity, it's like the "Tiling" value inside the material paramteres.

Comment: Does the aliasing not appear if you turn off the scaling and zoom further away?

Comment: LoL, actually I'm the stupidest person in the world. :) For some reason until now the mipmapping worked fine. I've found on the net that I have enable GL_TEXTURE_2D before the glGenerateMipmap function call. Probably I've updated my driver since the last time I've tested the mipmapping and for some reason I've not noticed the bug. Now I've added a new texture which looks too bad without it. I don't know why I didn't test things out properly. However, thanks for your replies!